# My application crashed when i click the clear option (code for clear is mpath.clear(); invalidates();)

Tags: android, android-canvas, clearcanvas

The app is **crashing** without clearing the canvas.
**android studio 3.3.2**

```
public void clearCanvas() {mPath.reset();invalidate();}
```

I expect to clear the canvas. without crashing

Comment: Can you please share the crash log?I think your mPath is null.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

You should share the crash log. 
In mostly case, you can find the reason of crash when you use try-catch block. You should try it, if you can't resolve it, you can ask more things in here.

In this case, you should check if your 'mPath' is null. (NullPointerException)